# Problem with joining dataframes using pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, inner-join

I have the following formula:

```
import pandas as pd 
houses = houses.reset_index()
houses['difference'] = houses[start]-houses[bottom]
towns = pd.merge(houses, unitowns, how='inner', on=['State','RegionName'])
print(towns)
```

However, the output is a dataframe 'towns' with **0 rows.**

I can't understand why this is given that the **dataframe 'houses'** looks like this:

```
State   RegionName
0   Alabama Auburn
1   Alabama Florence
2   Alabama Jacksonville
3   Alabama Livingston
4   Alabama Montevallo
5   Alabama Troy
6   Alabama Tuscaloosa
7   Alabama Tuskegee
8   Alaska  Fairbanks
```

And the **dataframe 'unitowns'** looks like this:

```
State   RegionName  2000q1  2000q2  2000q3  2000q4  2001q1  2001q2  2001q3  2001q4  ... 2014q2  2014q3  2014q4  2015q1  2015q2  2015q3  2015q4  2016q1  2016q2  2016q3
0   New York    New York    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 5.154667e+05    5.228000e+05    5.280667e+05    5.322667e+05    5.408000e+05    5.572000e+05    5.728333e+05    5.828667e+05    5.916333e+05    587200.0
1   California  Los Angeles 2.070667e+05    2.144667e+05    2.209667e+05    2.261667e+05    2.330000e+05    2.391000e+05    2.450667e+05    2.530333e+05    ... 4.980333e+05    5.090667e+05    5.188667e+05    5.288000e+05    5.381667e+05    5.472667e+05    5.577333e+05    5.660333e+05    5.774667e+05    584050.0
2   Illinois    Chicago 1.384000e+05    1.436333e+05    1.478667e+05    1.521333e+05    1.569333e+05    1.618000e+05    1.664000e+05    1.704333e+05    ... 1.926333e+05    1.957667e+05    2.012667e+05    2.010667e+05    2.060333e+05    2.083000e+05    2.079000e+05    2.060667e+05    2.082000e+05    212000.0
3   Pennsylvania    Philadelphia    5.300000e+04    5.363333e+04    5.413333e+04    5.470000e+04    5.533333e+04    5.553333e+04    5.626667e+04    5.753333e+04    ... 1.137333e+05    1.153000e+05    1.156667e+05    1.162000e+05    1.179667e+05    1.212333e+05    1.222000e+05    1.234333e+05    1.269333e+05    128700.0
4   Arizona Phoenix 1.118333e+05    1.143667e+05    1.160000e+05    1.174000e+05    1.196000e+05    1.215667e+05    1.227000e+05    1.243000e+05    ... 1.642667e+05    1.653667e+05    1.685000e+05    1.715333e+05    1.741667e+05    1.790667e+05    1.838333e+05    1.879000e+05    1.914333e+05    195200.0
```

Comment: And are you sure the values in `RegionName` is same across both tables? Since these are words separated by space, the join won't work if there is an extra space somewhere. Better practise might be to join the two words using a separator, or even better to create two columns.

Comment: It's very hard to tell where's the error. In the example provided, there's nothing to merge on

Comment: check for white space add a `str.strip()` to the columns before merging.